# Polybase with SQL Server 2019 on Linux or Containers

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, polybase, containers

I would like to install SQL Server 2019 on Linux either a full Linux server (Ubuntu 18.04) or on a Docker container with Polybase.  Installing MSSQL 2019 on a Linux Server or a container is relatively easy.  It's the Polybase bit that I cannot figure out.

Using the instructions at this Microsoft Docs site:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-linux-setup?view=sql-server-ver15

There is a reference to install Polybase on Ubuntu, which should be applicable in both cases (server or container).  When I attempted to install the Polybase packages on an Ubuntu server I got this result:

`sudo apt-get install mssql-server-polybase`

Installed without any issue

`sudo apt-get install mssql-server-polybase-hadoop`

`The following packages have unmet dependencies: mssql-server-polybase-hadoop : Depends: mssql-zulu-jre-11 but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

I could not find a solution to installing the package mssql-zulu-jre-11 on a Linux Server.

In a container, I logged in as a Root user and attempted the commands above:

`apt-get install mssql-server-polybase`

`E: Unable to locate package mssql-server-polybase`

I did verify that within the container the Linux instance has the correct sources for apt to find this package.  I am completely confused as to how to get Polybase running with SQL Server 2019 on Linux.  Have any of your had success?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: there is a hole guide, https://docs.azul.com/zulu/zuludocs/ZuluUserGuide/Title.htm

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Unfortunately, installing the Zulu JRE is not the solution.  I have tried to load the Zulu JRE via the instructions on the link you provided, but when I attempt to install the mssql-server-polybase-hadoop package, it is looking for a package called mssql-zulu-jre-11, not zulu11-jre.  In fact I get this output:
`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mssql-server-polybase-hadoop : Depends: mssql-zulu-jre-11 but it is not installable

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: as it goes um general computming and ubuntu, you should ask there for advice, as this is not a DBArelated question. usually atp get should resolve this automatically but as i remember correctly this was open source and that changed, at a first glance i foroun only a jdk 11 but no jre, maybe it is woth a shot

Comment: I understand your take on this, but I don't know who else would ever load Polybase for MSSQL Server but a DBA.  The package for Polybase requires the Microsoft variant of the Zulu JRE runtime -- no other one seems to work.  My hope was to run across another DBA that had to implement Polybase with MSSQL on Linux and had a solution to this problem.

Comment: as far as i understand ubuntu and linux, you add a reporsitory for the sources you need, (it is documented in the first link) then you use apt get to get those infomation and it depemndencies. You should really try the ubuntu community  as i said the only zulu that i found was the jdk https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/04/install-latest-openjdk-12-11-or-8-in.html

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error and a lot of research, I found a solution.

I tried both Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 18.04.  This installation approach works for both, but I only was able to get Polybase to work under Ubuntu 18.04.

I performed a fresh install of Ubuntu and SQL Server.  As with every attempt, everything went well except the installation of the mssql-server-polybase-hadoop package. It failed on attempting to find and install the mssql-zulu-jre-11 package.

However, I downloaded the .deb package and manually installed it from these locations:

Ubuntu 16.04:  https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod/pool/main/m/mssql-zulu-jre-11/mssql-zulu-jre-11_11.43.56-1_amd64.deb

Ubuntu 18.04:  https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod/pool/main/m/mssql-zulu-jre-11/mssql-zulu-jre-11_11.43.56-1_amd64.deb

After installing it with dpkg -i, I was able to then install the mssql-server-polybase-hadoop package.

This process allowed me to configure and use Polybase.  (Only with Ubuntu 18.04)